# add text in http request string url

Tags: java, java-me, request, httprequest

ok i made a midlet through which i can connect to server pages and get soem information as response.
For example i made a midlet through which i acced url: http://example.com/?u=nepal&t=1
Now i want to change the value of u as per users input.
I made a text field through which users can input desired name in u=*****
Now how can i add user inputted string to the url and featch it?
i tried to add the textfield directly to link it didnot worked.
i tried to pass s=textfield.getString();  and made url: example.com/?u="+s+"&t=1
But after i did it jar file donot run and says null exception error.
Please help how can i.. change the value of u as per users input through the app.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

NullPointerException means something is null - probably your textfield. Check it. It should work, if textfield isn't null.